# Concurrency problems in DB

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency

Currently I have next relation in DB 
parent:

```
@Entity
class Parent{

@OneToMany
private List<Child> childs;
}
```

and child

```
@Entity
class Child{

@ManyToOne
private Parent parent;
}
```

In case where two users at the same time will work on the one child element from the same list and save it in the same time. Will we have some problem with concurrency?

Comment: What is your [isolation](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/2/10/database-isolation-levels-and-their-effects-on-performance-a.html) Level?

Comment: This one  READ_COMMITTED.

Comment: So basically if your JavaCode is Threadsafe (means that not 2 Threads will manipulate the same Child) then the database will handle both save statements. This is something that is easy to test.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Isolation Level** ON your methods for entities.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
```

For reading and understanding of Isolationlevels:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.htm